# Copy ListBox to Clipboard, return carrier not conserved

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, mfc, clipboard

In a C++ application using MFC, i would like to be able to copy the entire CListBox content to clipboard.

I found a function which copy the content, neverheless, the return carrier aren't conserved.
I look with an HexEditor, and it appear there is $0A instead of $0D&$0A.

**Here is my code :**

```
CListBox * myListBox = (CListBox *)GetDlgItem(IDC_LIST_RESULT);
CString sContents = _T("");
CString temp = _T("");
int NumberOfSelections = 0;

NumberOfSelections = myListBox->GetCount();
for(int Selection = 0; Selection <= NumberOfSelections-1; Selection++)
{
    myListBox->GetText(Selection, temp);
    sContents += temp;
    sContents +="\n";
}

if (OpenClipboard())
{
    HGLOBAL clipbuffer;
    char * buffer;

    if (EmptyClipboard())
    {
        clipbuffer = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_DDESHARE, sContents.GetLength() + 1);
        buffer = (char*)GlobalLock(clipbuffer);
        CStringA ansiString(sContents); 
        size_t cbString = strlen(ansiString) + 1;
        strcpy_s(buffer, cbString, ansiString);
        GlobalUnlock(clipbuffer);

        if (SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, clipbuffer) == NULL)
        {
            CString msg;
            msg.Format(_T("Unable to set Clipboard data, error: %d"), GetLastError());
            AfxMessageBox(msg);
        }
        else
            AfxMessageBox(_T("Successfully copied selected laps to clipboard"));
    }
    else
        AfxMessageBox(_T("Unable to empty Clipboard"));
    CloseClipboard();
}
else
AfxMessageBox(_T("Unable to open Clipboard"));
// TODO: ajoutez ici le code de votre gestionnaire de notification de contrôle
```

I use unicode configuration with Visual Studio 2013.

Anyone have some ideas ?

Thanks a lot,

Best regards,

Nixeus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There only a `\n` because that's what you put in the clipboard.

```
sContents +="\n";
```

It should be

```
sContents +="\r\n";
```